# find xth td with td contains in same tr xpath python

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My page has a table with  11 columns, given text value for column 2, I want to click on the 11th column (arrow button) for the same row.

My DOM looks like this:

```
<table id=”atab”  width=”100%” class=”at-class”>`  
    <thead>…</thead>  
    <tbody>  
        <tr>...</tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>  
                <a href=”/abc/def/ghi/prop?id=1”>grp1</a>  
            </td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>200</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>…</td>  
            <td>  
                <ul class=”dropwd”  
                    <li class>  
                        <input class=”a-act a-menu-button” type=”button” value=”^”  
                        <ul class=”sub_menu” style=”vis””>…</ul>  
                    </li>  
                </ul>  
            </td>  
        <tr>  
    <tbody>
```

THIS WORKS (as I just grabbed the xpath from inspect element). I can’t use it though.

```java
myxpath = "//*[@id='atab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]/ul/li/input”
myxpath.click()
```

I need to use contains, then grab the sibling (11th position, 9th from where I have my contains). I tried the following for myxpath, but it cannot find the element. I have used same format elsewhere and it was fine. The only difference is this time, I am not getting the adjacent sibling but the xth sibling.

WHERE `campg = grp1`

```
//table[@class='at-class']//td[contains(text(),' " + campg + " ')]/following-sibling::td[9]/ul/li/input
//* [@id='atab']//td[contains(text(),' " + campg + " ')]/following-sibling::td[9]/ul/li/input
//* [@id='campaigns']//td[contains(text(),' " + campg +  " ')]/following-sibling::td[9]/ul/li/input[@type=’button’]
```

I tried other combinations too.

Comment: I would also do it with `following-sibling`. I wonder if your issue doesn't come from the spaces between your single and double quotes  `...' " + campg + " '...`. Also can you use a predicate on the  value of the button? (so as to not needing to know the extact position of the td containing your button). Something like this: `"//table[@class='at-class']//td[contains(., '" + campg + "')]/following-sibling::td//ul/li/input[@type='button' and @value='^']"`

Comment: Another thing, it's usually more readable to use `%` syntax to create your XPath expression: `"//table[@class='at-class']//td[contains(., '%s')]/following-sibling::td//ul/li/input[@type='button' and @value='^']" % campg`

Comment: I tried exactly what you said but it still couldn't find the element. The space was not an issue (it was a typo, i don't have spaces). I also tried with the predicates, still no luck. THe 2nd answer below worked perfectly. Thank you all the same for looking into it.

Comment: Indeed, @JensErat's answer is much cleaner. I still would recommend selecting the final input with something else than `td[11]` (I'm always wary of position constants in my expressions). But if `input[@type='button' and @value='^']` doesn't work, I'm out of advice without the original document to find out what's wrong with this predicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This XPath expression selects the table, looks for matching rows (in which the second column contains the needle you're searching for), then selects *in this row* the 11th column with the respecting input element.

No need to use any relative axis steps using ancestor and following, only descending the tree is usually faster, more readable and less error-prone.

```
//table[@id='atab']//tr[contains(td[2], 'needle')]/td[11]/ul/li/input
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this ! It works and much easier than having to deal with following-sibling.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should mark it as "accepted" (see the little checkmark on the left and [ask]).