# Selenium IDE with XPath to identify cell in table based on other column

Tags: xpath, selenium, ide, html-table, multiple-columns

Please take a look at the snippet of html below:

```
<tr class="clickable">
<td id="7b8ee8f9-b66f-4fba-83c1-4cf2827130b5" class="clickable">
<a class="editLink" href="#">Single</a>
</td>
<td class="clickable">£14.00</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to assert the value of td[2] when td[1] contains "Single". I've tried assorted variants of:

//td[2][(contains(text(),'£14.00'))]/../td[1][(contains(text(),'Single'))]

I've used similar notation elsewhere successfully - but to no avail here... I think it's down to td[1] having the nested  element, but not sure.

Can someone enlighten as to what I'm getting wrong? :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
//tr[contains(td[1], "Single")]/td[2]
```

First select the `<tr>` containing the `<td>` matching the text, and then select `td[2]`.

Then,

```
contains(//tr[contains(td[1], "Single")]/td[2], "£14.00")
```

should return `True`.

Or, closer to the expression you tried, you could test if this matches:

```
//tr[contains(td[1], "Single")]/td[2][contains(., "£14.00")]
```

See @JensErat's answer to [find xth td with td contains in same tr xpath python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075180/find-xth-td-with-td-contains-in-same-tr-xpath-python) .

Comment: Thanks that was perfect... and easy to extend to more than one conditional column! Much appreciated!

Comment: Nice to hear. If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it simple on yourself, do the if statement in your code.  Psuedocode:

1. Select the top level tr.
2. Find first td within tr, check to see if it contains Single.
3. If it does, assert that it contains £14.00

Alternatively, you could just get the text of the top level tr and perform the checks on that text.

Comment: That's not so simple; instead of using a half-dozen lines of code including branching, you could do the job with a single xpath.