# Selenium IDE, identify row in table based on 3 columns

Tags: css, xpath, html-table, multiple-columns, selenium-ide

I am trying to find a row in a table which contains specific values on three columns.

I have tried methods in @paul trmbrth's answer to [find XPath to identify cell in table based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109194/selenium-ide-with-xpath-to-identify-cell-in-table-based-on-other-column). Worked fine for 2 columns, but didn't worked with 3. I didn't find any example for cases with more than 2 values.

```
VEHICLE CATEGORY    |   CATEGORY    |   SUBCATEGORY

A   |   Exteriors   |   Badges

A   |   Exteriors   |   Badges

A   |   Exteriors   |   Mirrors

A   |   Interiors   |   Wheels

A   |   Interiors   |   Rears
```

Want cell with the combination that contains:

```
A   |   Exteriors   |   Mirrors
```

I have tried but no success:

```
//tr[contains(td[1], 'A')]/td[2][contains(., 'Exterior')] td[3][contains(., 'Mirror')]

//tr[contains(td[1], 'A')]/td[2][contains(., 'Exterior')] /td[3][contains(., 'Mirror')]

css=tr([td:contains('A')][td:contains('Exterior')][td:contains('Mirror')])

css=tr([td:contains('A')][td:contains('Exterior')][td:contains('Mirror')])
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of typos:

```
//tr[contains(td[1], '1') and contains(td[2], 'Eve') and contains(td[3], 'Jackson')]
```

But I'm not 100% this is most efficient, but it will work.