# Selecting a flexible element in Selenium IDE

Tags: select, click, selenium-ide

I'm having a problem in work, trying do this in Selenium IDE:

I need select a element in a list, but for this, I need identify it before. But there is some complications:

1) The table contains a lot of rows with differents products and this products receives an ID at the moment they are created, for example: if the classification is by creation order, the first element will receive an ID: xxxx-01-yyy, the second xxxx-02-yyy, etc... But this can change if the classification mode changes too. This row that represent a product contains lots of fields, and each field has a different ID too, having by commom the number of the position in the table.

2)The box that I need to click to select my element it is like a check box at the left side os the field with the name.

Anyone has an idea of how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide example HTML for the table please, as well as details of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Does a particular row in your product table has some text in one of the cells which is unique to the test case you are creating?

If this is the case see @paul trmbrth's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109194/selenium-ide-with-xpath-to-identify-cell-in-table-based-on-other-column) page.

If not, share the excerpt of HTML of your table and the function you are using.